# all possible permutations for a string

Tags: python, string

***Having a string='january' ,***

how can I generate following cases:

**case1(Replacing 1 character) =>** taking j and replace it with all ASCII letters(a-z). then do the same with: a , n , u , a , r , y.

Basically we would have

(Aanuary , Banuary ,..... ,Zanuary )+ (jAnuary , jBanuary .....jZanuary) + ....+(januarA , januarB , ....., januarZ)

I have done this part using following code, However, I have no idea how to do it for more than one letter since there are lots of permutations.

---

```
monthName= 'january'
asci_letters = ['a' , 'b' , .... , 'z']

lst = list(monthName)
indxs = [i for i , _ in enumerate(monthName)]
oneLetter=[]

for i in indxs:
word = monthName
pos = list(word)
    for j in asci_letters:
        pos[i] = j
        changed = ("".join(pos))
        oneLetter.append(changed)
```

***Case2: Taking 2 characters and replacing them:***
(AAnuary , ABnuary ,.....,AZanuary) + (BAnuary , BBanuary, .... , BZanuary) + (AaAuary , AaBuary,.....,AaZuary) + ...... + (januaAB , .... , januaAZ)

***Case3 :*** doing the same for 3 characters

***Case7:*** doing the same for 7 characters(length of string)

To summarize, I want to create all possible cases of replacing, 1 letter, 2 letters,3 letters,   up to all letters of a string.

Comment: So in case 1, you will have 7 `'january'`s?

Comment: you mean for the cases of replacing selected letter with similar one?(e.g:jAnuary , replacing a with A) if so , it would be better if we could avoid replacing with same letter otherwise I can handle this part after creating all permutations.@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Isn't that just all possible permutations for a string of 7 chars from a-z?

Comment: yes , it is .I will change the title now .Thanks @Igle

Comment: In my case I change characters , can we still count it as "All possible permutations" ? since in the cases I have checked for "All Permutations" , they were just considering all different cases for same string without changing any character (like ABC , ACB , CAB , ....)
@Igle

Comment: If I've done my math right, you have `Σ₁⁷26ⁿ·nCk(7,n) ≃ 1.1·10⁴⁷` possible combinations. Good luck ☺

Comment: Hope you are not good at math :))))) @pacholik

Comment: Ups, I guess I really em not ☺. Still `Σ₁⁷26ⁿ·nCk(7,n) = 10 460 353 202` combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that you can't hold all these permutations in memory because it will quickly become very crowded.

But to get all indices for the cases you can use `itertools.combinations`. For 1 it will give the single indices:

```
from itertools import combinations

string_ = 'january'
length = len(string_)
print(list(combinations(range(length), 1)))
# [(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,)]
```

Likewise you can get the indices for case 2-7:

```
print(list(combinations(range(length), 2)))
# [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), 
#  (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), 
#  (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
```

Then it's just a matter of inserting the `itertools.product` of `string.ascii_uppercase` at the given indices:

```
from itertools import product
import string

print(list(product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=1)))
# [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('E',), ('F',), ('G',), ('H',), ('I',),
#  ('J',), ('K',), ('L',), ('M',), ('N',), ('O',), ('P',), ('Q',), ('R',), 
#  ('S',), ('T',), ('U',), ('V',), ('W',), ('X',), ('Y',), ('Z',)]
```

Likewise for different repeats given the "case".

Putting this all together:

```
def all_combinations(a_string, case):
    lst = list(a_string)
    length = len(lst)
    for combination in combinations(range(length), case):
        for inserter in product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=case):
            return_string = lst.copy()
            for idx, newchar in zip(combination, inserter):
                return_string[idx] = newchar
            yield ''.join(return_string)
```

Then you can get all desired permutations for each case by:

```
list(all_combinations('january', 2))   # case2

list(all_combinations('january', 4))   # case4

list(all_combinations('january', 7))   # case7
```

Or if you need all of them:

```
res = []
for case in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:
    res.extend(all_combinations('january', case))
```

But that will require a **lot of memory**.

Comment: Thanks a lot man , I have tried it for two cases and it worked , without problem.However I am going on till the end  and will let you know if my notebook will be still alive :)
Nice work btw, thumbs up ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` for this, which gives you an `iterator` with all permutations:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

# First Param is an iterable of possible values, second the length of the 
# resulting permutations
combinations = combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',7)

# Then you can iterate like this:
for combination in combinations:
    #Do Stuff here
```

Don't try to convert this `iterator` to a list of all values, because you probably gonna get a `MemoryException`.

For your distance you might want to use python `distance` package. (You need to install it via pip first).

For your case, that you want to get all combinations for Characters a-z with length = 7 (because of January):

```
import distance
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

str_to_compary_with = "JANUARY"

for i in range(len(str_to_compare_with):
    combinations = combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', i+1)

    # Then you can iterate like this:
    for combination in combinations:
        # This is calculating the hamming distance for the combination with the string you want to compare to
        # Here you have to figure out yourself if you want to save that output to a file or whatever you wanna do with the distance
        hamming_dist = distance.hamming(''.join(combination), str_to_compare_with)
```

Comment: I need to create some kind of noise(Replacing letters) in month names ,  and then compute the edit distances(levenshtein , hamming , ...) by comparing  the original string with noisy one .
For this I need to consider all possibilities of replacing letters, considering NUMBER OF LETTERS TO REPLACE and POSITION OF NOISE.

Comment: Do you need the distances for each possible combination or just the highest, lowest, whatever distance?

Comment: basically for each possible combination , however do you have any suggestion if I just chose the lowest one?I mean does it make any difference in the sense of creating all permutations?@Igle

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how it is working, you can test this with a subset of letters, say from A-F:

```
x = []
for i in range(65,70): #subset of letters
    x.append(chr(i))

def recurse(string,index,arr):
    if(index>len(string)-1):
        return
    for i in range(index,len(string)):
        for item in x:
            temp = string[:i]+item+string[i+1:]
            arr.append(temp)
            recurse(temp,i+1,arr)

arr = []
recurse('abc',0,arr)
print arr
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do everything that you wanted with help of `product` and `permutations`:

```
from itertools import product, permutations

monthName= 'january'

letters = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

n = len(monthName)
indxs = range(n)
mn = list(monthName)

cases = {k: [] for k in range(2, n+1)}
for num in range(2, n+1):
    letter_combos = list(product(*[letters for _ in range(num)]))
    positions = permutations(indxs, num)
    for p in positions:
        for l in letter_combos:
            l = iter(l)
            for i in p:
                mn[i] = next(l)
            mn = ''.join(mn)
            cases[num].append(mn)
            mn = list(monthName)
```

Comment: Thanks , Will try it and comment the result.@zipa